# I have a B2 visa for the US, but I was admitted under the Visa Waiver Program. Now my ESTA will expire before I leave the US. What should I do?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas

My dilemma is that I was admitted to the US under my B2 visa on October 27 2017, my passport was stamped with a end of stay of April 26, 2018. (see first picture).

I then went to Iceland for 10 days and when I re-entered my passport was stamped again, but this time it was stamped with 'WT' not 'B2'. The departure date on this stamp was April 6, 2018 (he only gave me 90 days as he admitted me under the VWP and not my B2 visa). (see second picture)

My issue now is that my ESTA will expire at the start of March but I plan to stay in the US until mid April. Am I allowed to stay? Do I need to extend my ESTA or is my B2 visa enough? Can I depart on April 26th like my first stamp says, or do I have to depart before April 6th?

I hope this makes sense. Please help. Thank you.

[image: First stamp][image: Second stamp]

Comment: Related: [B1/B2 vs ESTA - Airline](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/109736/19400)

Comment: On a technicality ESTA is just permission to get on a plane. You were admitted under the Visa Waiver Program.

Comment: As @DJClayworth says the ESTA is a permission to fly (and sail) INTO the US. You're already in the US. Your ESTA is not a factor. Since you were let in under the VWP, you have until April 6 (not 26!).

Comment: It is a mutiple-entry visa, right?

Comment: No idea why this has been flagged as off-topic -- seems completely _on_ topic, to me.

Answer (score 18):

Your ESTA expiring in March is of no consequence.  You must leave by April 6 unless you get your admission record corrected.  You can ask at a [deferred inspection site](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/deferred-inspection/overview-deferred-inspection) to have this done.

> The Deferred Inspection Site staff is also available to review and issue the necessary documents to remedy errors recorded on arrival documents issued at the time of entry to the United States relating to improper non-immigrant classification, inaccurate biographical information or incorrect period of admission, if appropriate. Any designated deferred inspection location or CBP office located within an international airport should be able to assist you, regardless of where the actual document was issued.

If they do it, they should give you until July 6, six months after your second entry, but they might also give you until April 26th.

In the future, when you enter the US, present your passport open to the visa page.  Also, people who are traveling with a visa should not have ESTA, so if you don't get one in the future it will reduce the chance of similar confusion.

Comment: "people who are traveling with a visa should not have ESTA" People who are travelling with a visa shouldn't _get_ an ESTA. However, they might have one from a previous VWP entry -- ESTAs are valid for two years and, if you have one, there's no way to get rid of it.

Comment: "people who are traveling with a visa should not have ESTA" should read "people who are traveling with a visa do not need to have ESTA because the conditions met by ESTA are met by their visa".

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's a good point.  My statement is perhaps stronger than it needs to be.  I worded it like that because I've recently been reading about people who did get an ESTA even while holding a visa because they found they needed it to be able to use online check-in.  Those systems should be able to handle people with VWP-eligible passports who also have visas.

Comment: I already had my ESTA before I obtained my VISA. Thank you for the advice to give my passport open on the VISA page next time I cross the border. Thank you for addressing my problem clearly and precisely. I will be leaving the US in April to return to Australia, how long after I leave can I re-enter again under a B2 VISA?

Comment: @Yvette there's no need to write "visa" in all caps.  You can reenter immediately, but you do have to convince the immigration officer that you're not planning to live in the US; if your visits are too long or too frequent, you may have increasing difficulty with that.