# What does "BC" mean on a US entry stamp?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

What do the initials BC mean that were placed by US Immigration when they stamped my entry to the USA?  I entered through the port of Miami legally.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "B2" for the status you were admitted on? (B2 is the nonimmigrant status for personal visitors.)

Comment: @user102008 it's less likely, but also possible that the office wrote "B1" with a curvy `1`.

Comment: Could you post a picture?

Answer (score 6):

Almost certainly a B2/B1 stamp that looks like a C.

For example in a previous question ([I have a B2 visa for the US, but I was admitted under the Visa Waiver Program. Now my ESTA will expire before I leave the US. What should I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/109980/101)) you can see a B2 stamp where the '2' looks like a 'C' at first glance.